# What could cause a class implementing "ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>" not to be notified of a "ContextRefreshedEvent"

Tags: spring, spring-test

I have a **Spring application listener** implementing `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` as follows:

```
@Profile({ Profiles.DEFAULT, Profiles.CLOUD, Profiles.TEST, Profiles.DEV })
@Component
public class BootstrapLoaderListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>, ResourceLoaderAware, Ordered {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BootstrapLoaderListener.class);

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }

    @Autowired
    private DayToTimeSlotRepository dayToTimeSlotRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LanguageRepository languageRepository;

    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        initApplication();
    }

    private void initApplication() {
        if (dayToTimeSlotRepository.count() == 0) {
            initDayToTimeSlots();
        }
        if (languageRepository.count() == 0) {
            initLanguages();
        }
    }

    private void initDayToTimeSlots() {
        for (Day day : Day.values()) {
            for (TimeSlot timeSlot : TimeSlot.values()) {
                DayToTimeSlot dayToTimeSlot = new DayToTimeSlot();
                dayToTimeSlot.setDay(day);
                dayToTimeSlot.setTimeSlot(timeSlot);
                dayToTimeSlot.setDisabled(isDayToTimeSlotDisabled(timeSlot, day));
                dayToTimeSlotRepository.save(dayToTimeSlot);
            }
        }
    }
 ...
```

I rely on this listener class to insert reference data that is not updated nor deleted and I have a number of Spring integration tests that use this class, one of which fails because the listener is not notified (`initDayToTimeSlots` is not invoked).

I am trying to pinpoint where the problem comes from by debugging the tests and I noticed that when I run the problematic test class on its own, the tests contained in the class pass (indicating that the listener is notified) but when I run all of my application test classes together, the listener is not notified causing the test to fail (indicating that some other test changes/dirties the context).

Here is the problematic test class:

```
@ActiveProfiles({ Profiles.TEST })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { FullIntegrationTestConfiguration.class, BaseTestConfiguration.class })
public class RegularDayToTimeSlotsTest {

    private static int NUMBER_OF_REGULAR_DAY_TO_TIME_SLOTS_IN_WEEK = 25;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        //org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing.main(new String[] { "--url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:bignibou", "--noexit" });
    }

    @Autowired
    private AdvertisementService advertisementService;

    @Test
    public void shouldNotContainSaturdayNorSunday() {
        Set<DayToTimeSlot> regularDayToTimeSlots = advertisementService.retrieveRegularDayToTimeSlots();
        assertThat(regularDayToTimeSlots).onProperty("day").excludes(Day.SATURDAY, Day.SUNDAY);
        assertThat(regularDayToTimeSlots).onProperty("day").contains(Day.MONDAY, Day.THUESDAY);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotContainEveningNorNighttime() {
        Set<DayToTimeSlot> regularDayToTimeSlots = advertisementService.retrieveRegularDayToTimeSlots();
        assertThat(regularDayToTimeSlots).onProperty("timeSlot").excludes(TimeSlot.EVENING, TimeSlot.NIGHTTIME);
        assertThat(regularDayToTimeSlots).onProperty("timeSlot").contains(TimeSlot.MORNING, TimeSlot.LUNCHTIME);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldContainCorrectNumberOfDayToTimeSlots() {
        Set<DayToTimeSlot> regularDayToTimeSlots = advertisementService.retrieveRegularDayToTimeSlots();
        assertThat(regularDayToTimeSlots).hasSize(NUMBER_OF_REGULAR_DAY_TO_TIME_SLOTS_IN_WEEK);
    }
}
```

I am puzzled to see that both the `prepareRefresh()` and `finishRefresh()` methods within `AbstractApplicationContext.refresh` method are indeed called but that my listener is not notified...

Has anyone got any clue?

P.S. I know I could use `@DirtiesContext` in order to get a fresh context and I also know it would be preferable not to rely on an application listener for my tests but I am very anxious to understand what is going wrong here. Hence this post.

**edit 1**: When I debug the problematic test class in isolation, I notice that the event source is of type `GenericApplicationContext` and as explained above the test passes OK because the listener is notified. However when all test classes are run together, the event source is, oddly enough, of type `GenericWebApplicationContext` and no listener is found here in `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster`:

```
@Override
    public void multicastEvent(final ApplicationEvent event) {
        for (final ApplicationListener<?> listener : getApplicationListeners(event)) {
            Executor executor = getTaskExecutor();
            if (executor != null) {
                executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        invokeListener(listener, event);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                invokeListener(listener, event);
            }
        }
    }
```

**edit 2**: my comments in *edit 1* make me asks myself what is responsible for determining the uniqueness of context configuration...

For instance, I have only two test classes with the following context  configuration:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { FullIntegrationTestConfiguration.class, BaseTestConfiguration.class })
```

I guess they both will use the same cached context, won't they? Now can a third class use the same cached context even though it does not have exactly the same context configuration?

Why does my test get a `GenericWebApplicationContext` above?

Comment: Spring Test caches the application context and reuses it. Your listener should be called once and that is it as the context is being reused. Using a `ApplicationListener` for test data is a bit sketchy imho it should be part of your test class not some listener which might get invoked.

Comment: Thanks Marten. This is actually reference data and not test data and I am just asserting through a test that the reference data is as expected.

Comment: Still imho a bad case to use an `ApplicationListener` for, but as stated IMHO that is. How this is invoked heavily relies on how classes are loaded, which class instantiates the context first and maybe that has a different `@ActiveProfiles` who knows. Basically using the listener makes your test quite brittle. You are, imho, better of with a .sql script and a database initializer in your context.

Comment: Marten: I do understand your point but the purpose of this question is really to pinpoint and understand the technical reason why the listener is not notified (see P.S. in my post). Now to come back to the issue, I can rule out a Spring profile mismatch being responsible: I have checked that already. Any other idea?

Comment: I doubt that the listener isn't called. I is only called once at the start of your test suite. If there is some other test doing things with the database that might influence this test. The test context framework, as I mentioned before, reuses the application context, it will load it only once. Unless you use `@DirtiesContext` then it will disgard the context and initialize it again.

Comment: I agree with Marten's comments. If the Spring TestContext Framework is in fact loading your `ApplicationContext`, then the context most certainly gets refreshed (and exactly **once** as Marten points out). If you add some logging to your `BootstrapLoaderListener` you should be able to verify this.

Comment: Also, have you verified that your `BootstrapLoaderListener` is actually instantiated as a bean in the `ApplicationContext` specified via `{ FullIntegrationTestConfiguration.class, BaseTestConfiguration.class }`?

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you for your input. I am well aware that if all goes well the listener is notified once per test class.

Comment: @SamBrannen: the BaseTestConfiguration class is responsible for instantiating the listener and it is indeed instantiated.

Comment: I have edited my post with further relevant information.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you by any chance using `@ContextHierarchy` or `@WebAppConfiguration` anywhere in the affected test class hierarchy?

Comment: @SamBrannen: no the problematic test class doesn't use any of `@ContextHiearchy` nor `@WebAppConfiguration`...

Answer (score 1):

> my comments in edit 1 make me asks myself what is responsible for
>   determining the uniqueness of context configuration...

The elements that make up the context cache key are described in the [Context caching](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) section of the "Testing" chapter in the reference manual.

> For instance, I have only two test classes with the following context
>   configuration:
>
> @ContextConfiguration(classes = {
>   FullIntegrationTestConfiguration.class, BaseTestConfiguration.class })
>
> I guess they both will use the same cached context, won't they?

If they declare only those two configuration classes in that exact order, then yes.

> Now can a third class use the same cached context even though it does not
>   have exactly the same context configuration?

No.

> Why does my test get a GenericWebApplicationContext above?

A `GenericWebApplicationContext` is only loaded if your test class (or one of its superclasses) is annotated with `@WebAppConfiguration`.

If you are experiencing behavior that contradicts this, then you have discovered a bug in which case we would appreciate it if you could produce a scaled down test project in the [issue repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework-issues#readme) and [create a corresponding JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) against the "Spring Framework" and its "Test" component.

Thanks,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)

Comment: Thanks Sam! My test class is not annotated with `@WebAppConfiguration` . I have autowired an ApplicationContext variable in the test class and it is always of type GenericApplicationContext regardless of whether I run the test in isolation or with the others. Let me now try and confirm the type of the source for the ApplicationEvent event variable in the SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.

Comment: Sorry again about this false positive: I can confirm that the injected  `ApplicationContext` is always of type `GenericApplicationContext` and **not** of type `GenericWebApplicationContext` (at least for the two test classes that share the same cached context.)